# Use functions from a c++ dll stored as a resource, from within a c# wpf file

Tags: dll, embedded, resources, unmanaged, managed

I have a security dll which is built from unmanaged c++ code.
I would like to include this in my c# wpf project as an embedded resource, rather than as a separate dll on the file system.
At runtime I want to import the security dll from the resources and call functions from it.
Is that possible?
Thanks.

I have included the dll as a resource, but that is as far as I have got.